# How to use mouseclick area from loaded Form in qml?

Tags: qt, qml, qqmlcomponent

below is my code snippet where i'm loading qml ui using dynamic object creation method now i have to implement mousearea which reside in loaded file, can anyone help me to do this

```
Qt.createQmlObject(" import QtQuick 2.0

     Loader {
         id: pageLoader
         source: '/HomeScreenForm.ui.qml'
         anchors.fill: parent
         anchors.rightMargin: 0
         anchors.leftMargin: 0
         anchors.bottomMargin: parent
         anchors.topMargin: parent

         }


        ", rectangle7)
```

Comment: You can use the `Connections`-Type to connect Signals and Functions to other Signals. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#using-the-connections-type
For further help, a scetch-up of your loaded file would be necessary.

Comment: What a sense to create `Loader` with `createQmlObject`? Use `Qt.createComponent` instead.

Comment: Reason for using createQmlObject  is that i want to load qml file on rectangle7 and loaded file ui should be responsive @folibis

Comment: `createQmlObject` is the most unefficient way of creating Qml Objects. The only reason you might want to use it is, if the code within the string is completely dynamicaly generated, and there is no way of predicting anything of the structure. e.g. if you provide a QML-Editor within your application, where the user can write his own components... If you know the string beforehand, define it as a component, an use Component.createObject() to instanciate it, or a loader.

Comment: Yeah thank you @derM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom item contains `MouseArea`. To make the area accessible from outside you can use `alias`, for example:

*MyItem.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.7

Rectangle {
    id: root
    color: "yellow"
    property alias area: mouseArea

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Click me!"
    }
}
```

And then you can create it dynamically:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

Window {
    id: mainWindow
    width: 600
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("MyItem.qml");
        if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
            var obj = component.createObject(mainWindow);
            obj.width = 200;
            obj.height = 200;
            obj.anchors.centerIn = mainWindow.contentItem;
            obj.area.onPressed.connect(
                    function(mouse){ 
                        console.log("pressed at (", mouse.x,",",mouse.y,")")
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is using `Connections`, as @derM already noticed.

Comment: Nice, I was not aware of the fact, that you can set the id's as alias-targets. This will make my life easier!

Comment: Not sure why this needs ugly one-time loading via createObject(), as this can easily be done with a `Loader`, which then allows load-on-demand, unload, etc. on topof being nicely declarative